# Open Source Licensing New BSD steps

Tags: open-source, licensing

I've created some Java classes, is not a "product" nor a "program" which you can download and run it, is more like a library, not sure which is the proper name.

And I would like to know which are the steps to make it open-source.

I want to distribute it under the New BSD license.

http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php

Should I put the license inside of every Java class file that I want to distribute?
or should I put it into a text file named LICENSE.txt? if not, what should I do?

a question about the template:
Copyright (c) < YEAR>, < OWNER> <-- (there, should I include the '<','>') ?
All rights reserved.

is there something else I need to do?

After the licensing is done, when someone else use it for commercial purpose, it will be released as a product, how are they going to retain the copyright notice? will it be only inside of their codes? or should they somehow state which part or files are under the New BSD license?

Thanks.

Comment: "Library" would be the proper name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either approach is fine.
2. You're not supposed to include the less-than and more-than signs.
3. It says in the licence: "Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution."